# R ggmap, over-plotting ,points cover each other

Tags: r, ggmap

I have problem with over-plotting.

Situation looks like this: I have some data with coordinates and different place names, some place are in the same build - so I have same coordinates for few place names. How to plot it so they won`t cover each other? I tried with different shapes, the best option would be spreading those points or maybe plotting one point with few colours? But I don't have any idea how to do it. I will appreciate any help.

Code sample:

```
require(rgdal)
require(ggmap)
require(maptools)
require (plyr)

swd <- structure(list(nazwa = structure(c(8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
                                   5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("ODDZIAŁ CHIRURGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ", 
                                                                       "ODDZIAŁ GINEKOLOGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ", "ODDZIAŁ ONKOLOGICZNY", 
                                                                       "ODDZIAŁ ONKOLOGII I HEMATOLOGII DZIECIĘCEJ", "ODDZIAŁ ONKOLOGII KLINICZNEJ CHEMIOTERAPII", 
                                                                       "ODDZIAŁ RADIOTERAPII", "PORADNIA CHIRURGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ", "PORADNIA ONKOLOGICZNA", 
                                                                       "PORADNIA RADIOTERAPII"), class = "factor"), miasto = structure(c(8L, 
                                                                                                                                         8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("DZIAŁDOWO", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     "ELBLĄG", "EŁK", "GIŻYCKO", "MRĄGOWO", "NOWE MIASTO LUBAWSKIE", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     "OLECKO", "OLSZTYN", "OSTRÓDA", "PISZ", "SZCZYTNO"), class = "factor"), 
               dom = structure(c(17L, 5L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 18L, 5L, 17L, 17L, 
                                 20L, 17L, 19L, 17L), .Label = c("BARANKI 24", "GNIEŹNIEŃSKA 2", 
                                                                 "GOŁDAPSKA 1", "HENRYKA SIENKIEWICZA 4", "JAGIELLOŃSKA 78", 
                                                                 "JANA III SOBIESKIEGO 3 C/44", "KONOPNICKIEJ 1", "KOPERNIKA 30", 
                                                                 "KOŚCIUSZKI 30", "KRÓLEWIECKA 146", "KRÓLEWIECKA 146 146", 
                                                                 "LEŚNA 1", "MICKIEWICZA 10", "MICKIEWICZA 14", "OSEDLE MAZURSKIE 33 A", 
                                                                 "WARSZAWSKA 41", "WOJSKA POLSKIEGO 37", "ŻOŁNIERSKA 16B", 
                                                                 "ŻOŁNIERSKA 18", "ŻOŁNIERSKA 18 A"), class = "factor"), Lat = c(53.794077, 
                                                                                                                                 53.80182, 53.794077, 53.794077, 53.7827025, 53.7688275, 53.80182, 
                                                                                                                                 53.794077, 53.794077, 53.7696245, 53.794077, 53.7698809, 
                                                                                                                                 53.794077), Long = c(20.483249, 20.508952, 20.483249, 20.483249, 
                                                                                                                                                      20.4918876, 20.4903438, 20.508952, 20.483249, 20.483249, 
                                                                                                                                                      20.4927874, 20.483249, 20.492049, 20.483249)), .Names = c("nazwa", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                "miasto", "dom", "Lat", "Long"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 12L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               14L, 15L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L), class = "data.frame")
polska <- get_googlemap(
  center =c('Olsztyn, Polska'), 
  zoom=12, 
  maptype="roadmap" ,
  scale = 2 
  ,color = "bw"
)
kontury<- ggmap(polska)




punkty <- kontury+ geom_point( aes(x=Long, y=Lat, color=nazwa, shape=nazwa )
                               ,data=subset(swd,(  nazwa=='ODDZIAŁ GINEKOLOGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ'|
                                                     nazwa=='PORADNIA CHIRURGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ'|
                                                     nazwa=='ODDZIAŁ ONKOLOGII KLINICZNEJ CHEMIOTERAPII'|
                                                     nazwa=='PORADNIA ONKOLOGICZNA'|
                                                     nazwa=='ODDZIAŁ RADIOTERAPII'& 
                                                     miasto=="OLSZTYN"))
                               ,size=7

)+ 

  guides(fill  = guide_legend(ncol = 1)) + 
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(15,16,17,18,19,20), name="Symbol")

print(punkty)
```

[image: OUTPUT]

**UPDATE**
basing on the answer from **Philip** I did something like this:

```
require(rgdal)
require(ggmap)
require(maptools)
require (plyr)

swd <- structure(list(nazwa = structure(c(8L, 8L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 
                                          5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("ODDZIAŁ CHIRURGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ", 
                                                                              "ODDZIAŁ GINEKOLOGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ", "ODDZIAŁ ONKOLOGICZNY", 
                                                                              "ODDZIAŁ ONKOLOGII I HEMATOLOGII DZIECIĘCEJ", "ODDZIAŁ ONKOLOGII KLINICZNEJ CHEMIOTERAPII", 
                                                                              "ODDZIAŁ RADIOTERAPII", "PORADNIA CHIRURGII ONKOLOGICZNEJ", "PORADNIA ONKOLOGICZNA", 
                                                                              "PORADNIA RADIOTERAPII"), class = "factor"), miasto = structure(c(8L, 
                                                                                                                                                8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("DZIAŁDOWO", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            "ELBLĄG", "EŁK", "GIŻYCKO", "MRĄGOWO", "NOWE MIASTO LUBAWSKIE", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            "OLECKO", "OLSZTYN", "OSTRÓDA", "PISZ", "SZCZYTNO"), class = "factor"), 
                      dom = structure(c(17L, 5L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 18L, 5L, 17L, 17L, 
                                        20L, 17L, 19L, 17L), .Label = c("BARANKI 24", "GNIEŹNIEŃSKA 2", 
                                                                        "GOŁDAPSKA 1", "HENRYKA SIENKIEWICZA 4", "JAGIELLOŃSKA 78", 
                                                                        "JANA III SOBIESKIEGO 3 C/44", "KONOPNICKIEJ 1", "KOPERNIKA 30", 
                                                                        "KOŚCIUSZKI 30", "KRÓLEWIECKA 146", "KRÓLEWIECKA 146 146", 
                                                                        "LEŚNA 1", "MICKIEWICZA 10", "MICKIEWICZA 14", "OSEDLE MAZURSKIE 33 A", 
                                                                        "WARSZAWSKA 41", "WOJSKA POLSKIEGO 37", "ŻOŁNIERSKA 16B", 
                                                                        "ŻOŁNIERSKA 18", "ŻOŁNIERSKA 18 A"), class = "factor"), Lat = c(53.794077, 
                                                                                                                                        53.80182, 53.794077, 53.794077, 53.7827025, 53.7688275, 53.80182, 
                                                                                                                                        53.794077, 53.794077, 53.7696245, 53.794077, 53.7698809, 
                                                                                                                                        53.794077), Long = c(20.483249, 20.508952, 20.483249, 20.483249, 
                                                                                                                                                             20.4918876, 20.4903438, 20.508952, 20.483249, 20.483249, 
                                                                                                                                                             20.4927874, 20.483249, 20.492049, 20.483249)), .Names = c("nazwa", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "miasto", "dom", "Lat", "Long"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 12L, 13L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      14L, 15L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L), class = "data.frame")

swd <- data.table(swd)           # idk rly why but it didnt want to work w/o this command
setkey(swd,dom)
swd <- swd[swd[,.N,keyby=dom],.(dom,is.unique=N==1,nazwa,miasto,Lat,Long)]

olsztynOSM <- get_openstreetmap(bbox = c (left=20.4359, bottom = 53.7319, right= 20.5623, top= 53.81), scale = 40913, color = c('color'))

moja.paleta <- brewer.pal(9, "Set1") 
swd$kolor <- moja.paleta[swd$nazwa] 

konturyOSM<- ggmap(olsztynOSM)


punkty <- konturyOSM + geom_jitter(aes(x=Long,y=Lat,fill=nazwa), data = swd[!(is.unique)], width=0.006,height=0.006, size=7,pch=21) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Long,y=Lat,fill=nazwa), data = swd[(is.unique)], size=7, pch=25)+ 

  scale_fill_manual( values=setNames(moja.paleta,levels(swd$nazwa)),name='Legenda' ) + 
  guides(fill  = guide_legend(ncol = 1)) + 
  theme(legend.position="right") 

plot(punkty)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [geom_jitter](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_jitter.html) instead of `geom_point`. You can specify a `width` and `height` to adjust the amount of jitter.

From the documentation:

> `width`
>   Amount of vertical and horizontal jitter. The jitter is added in
>   both positive and negative directions, so the total spread is twice
>   the value specified here. If omitted, defaults to 40% of the
>   resolution of the data: this means the jitter values will occupy 80%
>   of the implied bins. Categorical data is aligned on the integers, so a
>   width or height of 0.5 will spread the data so it's not possible to
>   see the distinction between the categories.
>
> `height`
>   Amount of vertical
>   and horizontal jitter. The jitter is added in both positive and
>   negative directions, so the total spread is twice the value specified
>   here. If omitted, defaults to 40% of the resolution of the data: this
>   means the jitter values will occupy 80% of the implied bins.
>   Categorical data is aligned on the integers, so a width or height of
>   0.5 will spread the data so it's not possible to see the distinction between the categories.

**In response to your follow-up question in your comment:** Say you have some data with a column (or columns) that may or may not be duplicated across observations:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
x <- data.table(a=sample(1:5,10,replace=T))
setkey(x,a)

> x
    a
 1: 1
 2: 2
 3: 3
 4: 3
 5: 3
 6: 3
 7: 4
 8: 5
 9: 5
10: 5
```

Now we can add a column to indicate whether the value is unique or not: (**Edit to answer question in your other comment**: In data.table `.N` = count, so `x[,.N,keyby=a]` will return counts of observations, grouped by each occurrence of `a`. Additionally since I already set the key of `x` to be `a`, and use `keyby`, `x[,.N,keyby=a]` is itself a `data.table` with the same key as `x`, so `x[ x[,.N,keyby=a] ]` is a `data.table` *join*: it joins the extra column `N` in the inner table onto the columns in the outer one. Then `.(a,is.unique=N==1)` is a standard `data.table` operation to select a list of two columns, although I was lazy in not using more parentheses than necessary. This could also be read as `list(a=a,is.unique=(N==1))`. Note, the best way to make sense of these commands is to break them down and execute them step-by-step in your REPL, carefully looking at output, until you grok what each one does.)

```
pts <- x[x[,.N,keyby=a],.(a,is.unique=N==1)]
> pts
    a is.unique
 1: 1      TRUE
 2: 2      TRUE
 3: 3     FALSE
 4: 3     FALSE
 5: 3     FALSE
 6: 3     FALSE
 7: 4      TRUE
 8: 5     FALSE
 9: 5     FALSE
10: 5     FALSE
```

Let's add a column just to enumerate the observations for plotting:

```
pts[,b:=.I]
> pts
    a is.unique  b
 1: 1      TRUE  1
 2: 2      TRUE  2
 3: 3     FALSE  3
 4: 3     FALSE  4
 5: 3     FALSE  5
 6: 3     FALSE  6
 7: 4      TRUE  7
 8: 5     FALSE  8
 9: 5     FALSE  9
10: 5     FALSE 10
```

Now we can do a plot separating by whether the data would have been overplotted (note not literally for this data, since here I made all the x values different, but I think this is easy to visualize anyway), as I suggested in the comment:

```
ggplot(pts,aes(x=b,y=a)) +
    geom_point(data=pts[(is.unique)],color="blue") +
    geom_jitter(data=pts[!(is.unique)],color="red")
```

[image: Plot of ten points with default jitter]

Notice how only the unique values (blue) fall precisely on lattice points. We can adjust the jitter say to jitter points only vertically, and by less than default:

```
ggplot(pts,aes(x=b,y=a)) +
    geom_point(data=pts[(is.unique)],color="blue") +
    geom_jitter(data=pts[!(is.unique)],color="red",width=0,height=.2)
```

[image: Plot of ten points with no horizontal jitter]

By the way, unsolicited stylistic nitpick: if you give your color/fill and shape scales the same name, they'll combine and you can have a single better-looking legend. E.g.:

```
ggplot(pts,aes(x=b,y=a,color=is.unique,shape=is.unique)) +
     geom_point(data=pts[(is.unique)]) +
     geom_jitter(data=pts[(!is.unique)]) +
     scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"),name="Unique a?") +
     scale_shape_manual(values=c(15,16),name="Unique a?")
```

[image: Plot like first plot but with combined color and shape legend]

Comment: But then ill adjust all point not only the one with same coordinates for few place names, and I have much more points with single name on coordinate. In this data sample I presented only the problem, original data is much bigger. Or I am wrong? I`ll try it in second and write what I see.

Comment: If this is a big issue, you could split your data (either into two `data.frames`, or by adding a column to use as an indicator and using the `data` argument to `geom_point`), and then do two layers: one for unique data with `geom_point`, and one for would-have-been-overplotted data with `geom_jitter` (or equivalently with `width/height=0`). I've added a dummy MWE you should be able to tinker with to get your result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, your example is really usefully. I am gonna give it a try and I will try to add your idea to my script. Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you know why I cant use ggplot on a map ? When I try to I am getting an error:
`Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"` 

it works when I do it like that : 
`kontury<- ggmap(polska)
punkty <- kontury + geom_jitter(aes(x=Long,y=Lat,color=nazwa), data = swd, width=0.02,height=.05, size=7)` but I have problems with legend when I use 2 diffrent function: geom point and jitter both with aes inside.

Comment: And btw If you could explan this `x[x[,.N,keyby=a],.(a,is.unique=N==1)]` ? what is `,.N` for? I understand keyby and after that selecting columns.

I hope I'm not asking too much... I don't want to take too much of your time.

Comment: Typically the `non-numeric argument` error is when you aren't putting `+`s in the right locations. `+` needs to combine objects that `ggplot2` recognizes, so e.g. make sure you have no trailing `+`s after your last `geom`, and make sure your first object is a `ggplot()/ggmap()` etc.

Comment: I'll explain the syntax in the answer.

Comment: Also you can help avoid errors and also simplify your code by putting as many common aesthetics at the highest-level command as you can. So for example you probably want to do something like `ggmap(polska,aes(x=Long,y=Lat,color=nazwa,shape=nazwa)) + geom_point(data=....) + geom_jitter(data=....)` rather than repeating the `aes`s in each `geom`.

Comment: Theoretical your comment clarify everything but still I got tons of warnings and errors when trying to put aes in the higher-level (ggmap)... I updated my post adding script based on your answer so others can use it. Greetings :) Have a nice day! Thx again.